# How to get day (2-digit) from date string

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have a date string in variable called `dateEnd` like this `Mon Nov 20 2017 23:59:59 GMT-0200` on my react component and I want to extract the day (20) and convert it to a number.

This is my code:

```
let dateEnd = rangePicker['endDate'] && rangePicker['endDate'].toString();
```

How can I do this?

I've tried some like this:

```
let dateEndNum = parseInt(dateEnd.replace(/^\D+|\D.*$/g, ""), 10);
```

But returns me a error, because `.replace` is not defined.

In addition, I want to get the initial date and the end date to calculate how many days has between those dates.

Comment: it has nothing to do with React

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Comment: You can try [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) lib. `let endData = moment.utc('Mon Nov 20 2017 23:59:59 GMT-0200').date()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is not related with react. However I suggest you try out [`moment.js`](https://momentjs.com/) - it is a super powerful js library for handling datetime objects. In your case:

```
const momentDate = moment("Mon Nov 20 2017 23:59:59 GMT-0200");
const extractedDays = momentDate.date();
```

Comment: Thank you!
I just modified somethings like this:

`const dateIn = moment(rangePicker['startDate']).date();
 const dateOut = moment(rangePicker['endDate']).date();
 const stayDays = dateOut - dateIn;`

Answer (score 1):

This would return a boolean.

```
let dateEnd = rangePicker['endDate'] && rangePicker['endDate'].toString();
```

What you want is something like this:

```
let dateEnd = rangePicker['endDate'] ? rangePicker['endDate'].toString() : '';
```

Comment: Thank you. This returns me two strings correctly. But the moment.js save my day bring me the day number of selected date.

Answer (score 0):

Although this isn't related to React, I recommend using [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/), you can create a moment object using the date string, and one of the many functions can get you want you want.